# Как заставить танк общаться с сервером по TLS на основе ГОСТ-алгоритмов?

Tags: яндекс-танк, нагрузочное-тестирование

Как заставить Яндекс.Танк общаться с сервером по TLS на основе ГОСТ-алгоритмов?

Пробовал задать в load.ini

```
client_cipher_suites=+GOST2001-GOST89
```

или

```
ciphers=+GOST2001-GOST89
```

Никакого эффекта — нужные suite в ClientHello не появляются.
Конфигурация для OpenSSL правильная. Перед запуском Яндекс.Танк сделал

```
export OPENSSL_CONF=/root/wrk/openssl.cnf.ccgost
```

```
#cat /root/wrk/openssl.cnf.ccgost
openssl_conf = openssl_def

[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
gost = gost_section

[gost_section]
engine_id = gost
default_algorithms = ALL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

дело было в том, что phantom не читал openssl-ный конфиг. можно попробовать патч https://github.com/yandex-load/phantom/pull/4

deb пакет соберем позже

Comment: Это только для Gost engine от Криптоком
А как быть с Криптопрою У них свои контейнеры и как их читать? есть только их библиотека курл которая умеет читать по серийнику сертификата сертификат и закрытый ключ

Comment: фантом сам tls не реализует, работает с тем, что умеет openssl. Т.е вам нужно решить задачу "научить openssl работать с криптопро"